# How do I print all env vars beginning with the letter 'T'?

Tags: shell, env

This was an exercise for a course I'm on and I got really stuck at frustrated. I think my main problem is I keep putting the ">>" the wrong way round and then getting stuck in an editor which I don't know how to get out of!

I'm using Nitrous if that makes any difference.

Comment: You don't need any editor for that, just run `env | grep '^T'`.

Comment: How shall we know if you use `>>` the wrong way if we don't know anything about what you have done...?

Comment: the examples show for the syntax to be ">>" instead of "<<", "<<" seems to open somethign in the console... I really have no idea what im doing

Comment: ok Jimmij really helped, how do i append that to the end of a file? i thought I knew how

Comment: ok i lost what i originally put, but it was pretty much printenv >> t-vars.env .... this jsut put me into a zone where every time i pressed enter it just skipped a link instead of finishing my command... sorry I can't describe it any better

Comment: I think I guessed what this could be about. You used `<<` in a terminal which started an ["here-document"](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) which you didn't know how to terminate ? Your question is really unclear, you don't even say if you are typing in a text editor, a terminal, and what *exactly* you typed ...

Comment: @Leiaz yes, that's possible. Another possibility is that he used unpaired quote somewhere, something like `printenv >> 'file.env`. To quit from this nonsense use `Ctrl-C`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use any `>>` Just type `env | grep ^T`.

Comment: That matches on _lines_ starting with T. Both env var names and values can be made of several lines. Also note that `^` is special in many shells (Thomson, Bourne, zsh -o extendedglob, fish, rc, es, akanga), so is best quoted.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, but at least on my computer, typing `env` shows every variable in a new line.

Comment: Then try `env -i $'A\nT_WRONG=B\nT_WRONG_AGAIN' env` (that's the output for _one_ env var (`A<newline>T_WRONG`).

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there's no portable solution especially if you want to consider variables with no value part or duplicate variables. On a recent GNU system:

```
env -0 | grep -z '^T' | tr '\0' '\n'
```